# How do I run Chrome on docker container with GPU attached but no monitor?

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver, nvidia

We want to set up chromedriver with GPU & no monitor on kubernetes cluster on GKE. I got to a point where I do have nvidia drivers installed, `nvidia-smi` works just find and I'm stuck at this point.

How do I run Chrome on docker container with GPU attached but no monitor? My idea is to simply run X server for that purpose, but cannot seem to get it working with no monitor.

Any suggestions welcome!!!